# Multiple dex files define Lio/codetail/animation/SupportAnimator$AnimatorListener;

Tags: java, android

I hope anybody can help me here. I am struggeling to my wits end with this and I cannot figure out what is wrong. I tried every solution in every similar post yet nothing worked.

My build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            minSdkVersion 18
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        }
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
    dependencies {

        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
            exclude module: 'httpclient'
        }
        compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')

        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta3'

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'

        //compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.github.zomato:androidphotofilters:1.0.1'
        //compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
        compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
        compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
        compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
        compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.5.0'

        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.0.1'
        compile 'com.unipiazza.materialtwostepslogin:materialtwostepslogin:0.1.4'
        compile 'com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The issue started whe I added the library:

```
com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1
```

It seems to be quite clear that there is a duplicate library somewhere that is also used in the com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1 library But for the life of me I cannot figure out what or where and how to exclude it.

Help will be very much appreciated.

EDIT:

As suggested by crickets_007 in the comments (i think), I have run a dependancy report by going to the Gradle projects window and navigating to MyAppName > :app > Tasks > android and double clicking on androidDependancies which produced the dependancy report at the following link:

```
http://pastebin.com/u8Rtm9uu
```

Unfortunately I am not sure how to use this and what to do with this information.

I have also removed the com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1 line from the gradle and recompiled the project as asked in the comments section and it works 100% so the problem is definitely something within tht library. Question is what and how do I exclude it???

EDIT:

What I have noticed is that

```
com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1
```

has the following in it's Gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.asyl.animation:arcanimator:1.0.0'
```

Which can be seen here: https://github.com/gowong/material-sheet-fab/blob/master/material-sheet-fab/build.gradle

The following Library:

```
compile 'com.github.asyl.animation:arcanimator:1.0.0'
```

in turn has the following in it's Gradle:

```
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
```

I cannot find nineoldandroid anywhere in my dependancy report but a lot of these errors I saw online is caused by this library which I find quite interesting.

Comment: Try moving all `com.android.support` dependencies to the top and make sure they are all the same version. You should update `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7` to `25.x.x`.

Comment: Thanks Jared, I will try this this morning and revert back.

Comment: Hi Jarred, tried this and the same issue still persists. I also tried cleaning the solution after making the change but still the same errors. I have edited the build.gradle code in the above question to reflect the changes. Please note that I tried adding the com.android.support libraries both before and after the compile fileTree and compile files tags but still no luck!

Comment: Use  `multiDexEnabled` true for `defaultConfig` in `build.gradle`

Comment: I can't help but notice you have many libraries. At least 4 of those can perform HTTP requests. I suggest you figure out what you really need. You seem to have narrowed your search to the material-sheet-fab, though. Does the app build if you comment that one out? Do you have any JAR files in the libs folder that could conflict?

Comment: If you really want to debug the process, you can run `./gradlew app:dependencies` from the terminal within your project

Comment: Piyush, I read about this in other posts but I'm trying to stay away from this for as long as possible as the feeling i am getting is that it's a dirty solution to the problem and might have reprocussions. Thanks anyway. I will try this as a last resort.

Comment: cricket_007, Yes I have a few. Although I have not tried removing the line as yet I assume it will work as the issue started immediately after I added that line, added the code that references the library and ran the project. Process: Ran Project and tested successfully > added com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1 to gradle > added code that references com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1 > Ran project to test (build failed with error). I will however remove all my code that references the com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1 and remove it from the build.gradle to test.

Comment: cricket_007, as for the libraries, yes there are a few and all of them are being actively used. I do have another httplib jar file in my libs folder but I already tried removing that and rebuild the project but it still failed (different) errors though because I am using it but still failed none the less. I also tried uncomenting all the libraries in the gradle that I thought I am not using but alas I am using them. I will however go through this process again one by one to see if there are any that I can remove when I test removing the sheetfab library after a successful build.

Comment: cricket_007, I tried (not sure if it is the same process) running a dependancy report in the gradle window which gives me a huge tree of dependancies. As this is my first android project I am struggling to make sense of the report and am not sure how to read it and it did not bring me any closer to an answer. Guidance in this might though. Alternatively, how do I run your suggested command in android studio if your process is different? PS: thanks for all your input.

Comment: @cricket_007, I have perform the tests and run a dependancy report. I have edited the question to reflect the information gathered during this process. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a known issue, by the way.  https://github.com/gowong/material-sheet-fab/pull/29

Comment: @cricket, I solved this two hours ag by further investgation into the library dependancies and coming accross that exact same link. I can just laugh. Anyway. Would you care to post that link as the answer so i xan choose it? I was going to post the answer but you helped me so muc to go in the right direction I would prefer if I could choose your answer.

Comment: Youre welcome to answer your own question to document your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I drilled down into the dependacies of the

```
com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1
```

library. The library includes the

```
com.github.asyl.animation:arcanimator:1.0.0
```

library as a dependancy. Checking its dependancies I found it included the

```
com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0.
```

DING DING!! What further made this interesting and was that the source on github is

```
ArcAnimator/sample/src/main/java/io/codetail/arcsample/
```

This looks very similar to my error.

The nineoldandroids library is a library is a name I have seen many times in threads about related "clashing" issues. I started to look deeper into my other libraries.

What sealed the deal was when I looked into the other libraries that I include. Upon drilling into the

```
com.unipiazza.materialtwostepslogin:materialtwostepslogin:0.1.4
```

library I noticed that it includes the

```
com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.1@aar
```

library. When browsing this library there is a source path on github which looks like this:

```
CircularReveal/circualreveal/src/main/java/io/codetail/
```

You will notice that this also looks similar to my error. 
I went back to the inital library

```
com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1
```

as I have now found my two conflicting libraries. I checked the issues tab to see if I have previously missed something but alas, this page was fruitless. I then noticed someone did a pull request and went to that tab (I was feeling lucky. Maybe this guy fixed it). AND BINGO:

[io.codetail library removal from the project and included as a dependency](https://github.com/gowong/material-sheet-fab/pull/29)

I followed through this thread and came to an answer as to how to exclude this library.

Even though all of this could have been avoided if I had just checked the pull request page before I went on a wilde goose chase, it eventually paid off.